# URL pattern issue with Struts 1.x and Struts 2.x

Tags: java, regex, struts2, xml-configuration, deployment-descriptor

One of my project is running on Struts 1.x and We are trying to integrate few of URL's pattern on struts 2.x. Few URL also end with `Abc.do` .

Currently `web.xml` looks like:

```xml
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>config</param-name>
          <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And above pattern working fine as defined in `web.xml`.

Now we have added in `web.xml` to support Struts 2.x parallel.

```xml
<filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class> 
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

After added above info in `web.xml` , those URL pattern ends with `.action` they are also working fine using struts 2.x.

But when we want to add few specific URL pattern which also ends with `.do` mapped to Struts 2.x as below.

```xml
<filter-mapping>
         <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
         <url-pattern>/Hello.do</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

We want all request which starts with `Hello*.do` should mapped on struts 2.x , but right now this is not happening.

So is am something missing here in `web.xml` or Altogether it is not possible.

Is there any way apart we can solve this issue?

Comment: First of all, your `Hello` mapping doesn't reflect what you're actually trying to do; I see no wildcard there. Second, the *order* of mappings is significant, you need to have them from most-to-least significant. Third, mapping S2 to anything other than * is fraught with issues if you're not absolutely sure what you're doing.

Comment: Struts1 + Struts2 together has been tried before. [It didn't work out so well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Island_of_Doctor_Moreau)...

Comment: I want all URL pattern start with Hello should go through struts 2.x. but these patterns end with .do e.g. Hello.do

Answer (score 0):

First you should define Struts2 filter and let it map all URLs including `/Hello*.do` pattern along with `*.action` pattern. Then follows Struts 1 filter that maps `*.do`. The `struts.xml` should be configured to exclude patterns that ends with `.do` except `/Hello*.do`.

**`struts.xml`:**

```xml
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="(?!/Hello.*).*\.do"/>
<constant name="struts.action.extension" value="action,do,,"/>
```

**`web.xml`:**

```xml
<!-- Struts2 configurations -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Struts configurations -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>config</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: URL pattern /Hello*.do not accepting in above web.xml

Comment: Yes, I changed the pattern.

Comment: thanks Roman, now behavior is if request is coming with Hello*.do then it is still going into struts1 xml and if request is without .do like Hello* is working fine.But we need with Hello*.do. Is there any needs to change in this pattern (?!/Hello.*).*\.do ????

Comment: No need to change, struts2 filter should handle the request. If servlet is still invoked then you need to override the struts1 request processor to prevent processing already handled by struts2 request.

Comment: thanks Roman, yes servlet is still invoked by Hello*.do (it is not going into struts.xml).Can you elaborate how to  override the struts1 request processor to prevent processing already handled by struts2 request??????

Comment: Add `<constant name="struts.action.extension" value="action,do,,"/>`. It will handle `Hello*.do` but not other struts2 actions with `.do` because they are excluded. Use `.action` for struts2 actions.

Comment: thanks again Roman, as per user given solution Now it is working with Hello*.do .but as you have already told Now we can't do same with another like Welcom*.do so that's why it is not useful for us.because  here we have 6 7 url those are with .do and want to redirect to struts2.Is there any another solution for this problem???need your help

Comment: You can modify exclude pattern to match other URLs like `(?!/(Hello|Welcom).*).*\.do`, but it seems different question. You have asked how to *map* actions. Now you asking how redirect them. I don't understand it because it's different thing.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Now you can mark it as accepted solution, if you don't know how to do that see http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Now its working---

In Web.xml--

```
 <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
 <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
        </filter>
```

In Struts.xml---

```
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="(?!/(Hello|AbcOn|Person|School).*).*\.do"/>
             <constant name="struts.action.extension" value="action,do,,"/>
```